# Keycloak Identity Provider with Canva SSO

Tags: keycloak

I try use Canva SSO by using Keycloak as my identity provider. I have follow all Canva document
[canva link](https://www.canva.com/help/set-up-sso/)

Error when I try to login in canva.com with my verify domain and it redirect to my keycloak with an error message Invalid Request:
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mppbZ.png)

My client's configuration in Keycloak

[My Client Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5A8Q3.png)

[My Client Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJq8y.png)

[Saml Attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6Svs.png)

Keycloak Realm Identity Provider MetaData:
[Keycloak MetaData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBuV3.png)

Canva SSO Configuration: [configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fY7D.png)

In my opinion, the problem may be in the SAML 2.0 HTTP Client or SAML Attribute, but I do not know how to solve it.